# Why are these two groups isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

$\langle x, y \mid x^7 = e, y^3 = e, yxy^{-1} = x^2 \rangle$ and $\langle x, y \mid x^7 = e, y^3 = e, yxy^{-1} = x^4 \rangle$. Is it because $x^4 = (x^2)^2$, or is this the wrong reason why they are the same?

Comment: Using the first set of generating relations, $y^2xy^{-2} = y(yxy^{-1})y^{-1} =yx^2y^{-1}=yxy^{-1}yxy^-{1}=x^2.x^2=x^4.$ Thus the $y$ in the second set of generators  is a lable for $y^2$ in the first set. This is true since the order of $y$ in both cases is prime.

Comment: Well, in the presence of the other relations, the relation $yxy^{-1} = x^2$ is equivalent to $x = y^{-1} x^2 y$, which is in turn equivalent to $y^{-1} x^2 y = (x^2)^4$. If $G_1$ denotes the first group and $G_2$ denotes the second, then this suggests an isomorphism $G_2 \overset{\sim}{\to} G_1$ given by $x \mapsto x^2$ and $y \mapsto y^{-1}$. Then you just need to check that this is indeed a well-defined homomorphism and an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $G=\langle x,y\mid x^7=e,y^3=e,yxy^{-1}=x^2\rangle$.

Now, in $G$, we have 
$$y^2xy^{-2}=y(yxy^{-1})y^{-1}=yx^2y^{-1}=yxy^{-1}yxy^{-1}=x^2x^2=x^4.$$
Since $G$ is generated by $x$ and $y^{-1}$, writing $z=y^{-1}$ gives a presentation
$$G=\langle x,z\mid x^7=e,z^3=e,zxz^{-1}=x^4\rangle.$$
This shows the groups in your post are the same.

Comment: this last presentation would be $\langle x,z\ |\ x^7=e, z^3=e, x=z\rangle$ then?

Comment: @janmarqz thanks. fixed.